# Difficulty with Securing Static Files with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-authorization

(updated based on feedback from Menno)

I have a request to secure a folder full of static files (htm, pdf, etc) using the ASP.NET authorization that secures the rest of the site.  The folder is in the root of the web.  Normal ASP.NET authorization works fine for the web.  The only issue is securing this particular folder.

I'm attempting to reconfigure the ASP.NET authentication modules so that they're invoked for all files in my "Documentation" folder using the following in the web.config at the root of my application:

```
<location path="Documentation">
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
            <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
            <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
            <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

No effect.

If I put that same system.webServer node in a web.config in the Documentation folder -- no effect.

It only takes effect if I put that same system.webServer node in a web.config in the Documentation folder and then convert the Documentation folder into an application.

I haven't seen any information that says you can successfully use a system.webServer node inside a location node, but I also haven't seen and information saying there's any restrictions on what's used inside a location node.

The application pool is running 4.0, Integrated mode.  Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running your application pool in Integrated mode, or in classic mode?

Comment: Integrated mode.  Also updating my original post to reflect this.

Comment: I just tried it out in a test project, and the first method works like a charm for me. It also seems more elegant than option 2.
Are you sure you weren't looking at cached versions of your downloadables when testing?
Either way, I would suggest looking into option 1 again, because
1) According to my concept of how IIS and ASP.NET work, it should work, and
2) for me, it does work.

Comment: More information -- I overrode the modules in a web.config inside my "Documentation" folder because I don't want *every* file in the application to be secured.  Adding this into my original post.

The system is ignoring the web.config in the "Documentation" folder.  I'm attempting to solve that issue now.

Comment: You can set the authorization modules to run for all requests in the root web.config. Just having those modules run doesn't change anything about the actual read permissions. It just forces ASP.NET to also check those permissions for your static files. Securing the files themselves you're still doing using the `<authorization>` element. Securing a specific folder I usually like to do using a `<location>` block in the root web.config. It's just neater to have all your set permissions right there in the same place.

Comment: True, but if you have the modules execute for all files from the root, all the files referenced by the login page (scripts, images, styles, etc.) are secured and not available until the user has logged in.

Overriding the modules in a web.config in the Documentation folder doesn't work.

Overriding the modules in a `location` node in the root web.config doesn't work.

Converting the Documentation folder into an application and overriding the modules does work.  Not my first choice, but so far it's the only viable option.

Comment: You could also set authorization to `<add users="*">` on your scripts and images folders that you use for your login page.